# How do you deal with homonyms in a list?

Tags: lists, homophones, homonyms

I was thinking about it, and, is there a proper way to deal with having homonyms in a list? Would you characterize it as one object, for example:

> I have two notebooks in my bag.

Or would you treat it as two separate objects, for example:

> I have a notebook and a notebook in my bag.

I feel that the second option does not sound right, and the first option doesn't seem right because they are two different objects, it may confuse somebody into thinking that you have multiple of the same item.

I know that it would be much better to say something like:

> I have a laptop notebook and a spiral notebook in my bag.

But, the notebook example was the only example I could think of off the top of my head.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you would say you have a notebook computer and a spiral notebook in your bag.  At the very least you should somehow qualify them and not say either "two notebooks" or "a notebook and a notebook".  (Or simply say "I have some stuff in my bag.")

Comment: When you use a word in two of its senses (polysemes, not homonyms, which are different words), it is almost mandatory to add disambiguating modification. _He didn't take the corner from the actual corner._ // 'I don't like coffee unless it's _coffee_ coffee. 'Sometimes, it's just ridiculous to use them close together ?? _That beast is a beast_. Rephrasing is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would depend on the intent of the author.

If the intent is to be clever or to confuse the audience for some effect then they may do something like your first example.

> I have two bats in my gym bag. Would you grab one please?
>    [Other guy opens the bag and a vampire bat flies out. He falls on his behind. Audience laughs]

If the intent is be clear about the the subject then your third example would be a good choice.

Answer (score -3):

Can't help, but you got me thinking, is the e.g. 'U.S. army' not the same as your notebooks, meaning that usually **Navy, Army and Air Force** are treated as one incorrectly in sake of 'convenience'!  One would think that **Navy** and **Air Force** didn't take part in D-DAY if you read this excerpt from an American web-site:
*The U.S. Army remembers June 6, 1944: The World War II D-Day invasion of Normandy, France.*

Comment: Who is that smartass that put me under water!  I couldn't put my attempt to help in comment section because site asked me for 50 reps, that's why I gave an 'answer'. In my opinion, people who downvote people who try to help while staying anonymous are at best smartasses.

Comment: I didn't downvote, as you're new here, Georgi. Hello. But if you really want to help, stick within the guidelines laid down in the Help Center. Though any 'answer' that starts 'Can't help ...' is very likely to get downvoted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks Edwin, I am intelligent enough and that thought crossed my mind, but you see, my love for English language is always before timidness/shyness of any kind, that is, I am brave enough to jump into the deep water but when someone tries to drown me my reaction is negative especially when I am new to the forum and the rules didn't allow me to comment. Maybe the designers have to have a second thought on this fact: to be able to comment comes first before being able to answer not vice versa, I think.

Comment: Is there a good reason why new new members should have more special treatment than the old new members did?

Comment: Sure, to put you under water when you first enter the sea is as good as when a novice is being kicked every time he errs. Do you say to your guests 'you punk get out' when they don't comply to your dresscode/talkcode/...

Comment: Edwin, just to clarify with one example concerning shoecode, he-he. In the farwest e.g. America in contrast to the fareast e.g. Japan it is a wide-spread habit to put one's feet (with shoes) on the couch/table while in Japan it is an unwritten law that you have to boot off in the very entry, not knowing the rules is excusable only for people unaware of them, it is up to the host what will happen if they are 'broken'.

Comment: There _are_ written laws in ELU. And the 'host' has already 'shown what will happen if [people don't accept them]'. Ignorance of the law is no excuse in law. It's just that people can't be bothered to read / comply with the ELU regulations, but want to redefine the site according to personal likings. I think the rules here are sometimes crazy, and have been known to break the occasional one. You could comply and still make your point by posting a question (Is there a word to describe the loose and disrespectful dropping of the names of some of the ... ?) Though we call them 'the Armed Forces'.

Comment: I have now added my downvote. Even as a new member, you've had enough time to remove your self-styled ('Can't help = unhelpful) non-answer. It would make a _good_ and interesting comment. Man up, and get the few reputation points a 'comment' requires. Don't be a queue-jumper.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Your 'reasoning' is too pedantic and with no substance to me, you propose me to wait for 50 points and just then to help Jeff!? You say 'man up', here you're wrong again, I consider myself an oldboy and this way I wanna live my life, as for 'queue-jumper', you are wrong again - I do want to help Jeff before the "queue".

Comment: And you start helping him by saying 'Can't help, but ...'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What I meant was to clarify that I was not able to answer, what drove me to comment (disguised as an answer) was the 'Army' example, I wanted to share with Jeff similar bogus.